# Ajuda com erro '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
nome_usuario = input('Informe o seu nome: ')
idade_usuario = int(input('Informe sua idade: '))
peso_usuario = float(input('Informe seu peso: '))
peso_desejado = float(input('Qual o peso desejado? '))
vezesMalhou = 0

def malhar(idade, peso):
    
  if (idade < 28):
     peso = - 2
  else:
     peso = - 1

while (peso_usuario > peso_desejado):
peso_usuario = malhar(idade_usuario, peso_usuario)
vezesMalhou = vezesMalhou + 1

print('{} você precisa malhar {} vezes para chegar no seu pesodesejado.'.format(nome_usuario, vezesMalhou))
```

Answer (score 1):

Há dois erros principais no seu código: o que justifica a mensagem de erro que colocou e outro que provavelmente não notou visto que o primeiro erro supriria o segundo.

A função `malhar` que você definiu não possui uma cláusula de retorno e, por padrão no Python, funções sem esta cláusula irão retornar o valor `None`. Assim, quando você faz:

```
while (peso_usuario > peso_desejado):
  peso_usuario = malhar(idade_usuario, peso_usuario)
  vezesMalhou = vezesMalhou + 1
```

O valor de `peso_usuario` irá receber o valor `None` já na primeira vez que chamar a função `malhar`, o que justifica a mensagem de erro dizendo que não é possível verificar se `None` é maior que um número (`peso_usuario > peso_desejado`).

O segundo erro está no corpo da função malhar:

```
def malhar(idade, peso):
  if (idade < 28):
     peso = - 2
  else:
     peso = - 1
```

Pois basicamente o que você fez foi atribuir o valor `-2` se a idade for inferior a 28 e `-1` caso contrário. Assim, já na primeira chamada a esta função seria como se o peso do usuário ficasse negativo, o que não faz sentido algum, incluindo fisicamente. Acredito que a ideia aqui seria reduzir o peso em 2 (ou 1, dependendo da idade) e para isso você deve inverter a ordem os operadores: ao invés de `=-` colocar `-=`. Ou pode ainda simplificar já retornando o valor (o que corrige o primeiro erro):

```
def malhar(idade, peso):
  if (idade < 28):
     return peso - 2
  return peso - 1
```

Comment: "*incluindo fisicamente*" - claro que no caso da pergunta não faz sentido mesmo, mas: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396398 | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tire os parênteses do **if** e **while**, dê o retorno do peso no método **malhar** e corrija a indentação.

```
def malhar(idade, peso):
   if idade < 28:
       peso -= 2
   else:
       peso -= 1
   return peso 

nome_usuario = input('Informe o seu nome: ')
idade_usuario = int(input('Informe sua idade: '))
peso_usuario = float(input('Informe seu peso: '))
peso_desejado = float(input('Qual o peso desejado? '))

vezesMalhou = 0

while peso_usuario > peso_desejado:
   vezesMalhou += 1
   peso_usuario = malhar(idade_usuario, peso_usuario)     

print(f'{nome_usuario} você precisa malhar {vezesMalhou} vezes para chegar no seu peso desejado.')
```